# Char Array concatenation format in C

Tags: c, arrays

So today I was messing around with some string parsing in C and I started receiving an odd string formatting. I believe it has something to do with the strcat between the array "functionName" and the pointer "fiterator", but I cant figure out how to fix it:

I'm trying to print "test()" but rather i'm receiving test()est()st()t()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void __INTERFunc(char args[])
{
  char * argsp;
  char functionName[25] = {};
  for (argsp = args; *argsp != '\0'; argsp++)
  {
    if (*argsp == '(')
    {
      char *fiterator;
      for (fiterator = args; *fiterator != '('; fiterator++)
      {
        strcat(functionName, fiterator);
      }
    }
  }
  char * nmiter = functionName;
  while (*nmiter != NULL)
  {
    printf("%c", *nmiter);
    nmiter++;
  }

  // This block is for testing purposes
  // Still receiving output: test()est()st()t()
  printf("\n");
  printf("%s\n", functionName);


}

int main()
{
  __INTERFunc("test()");
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is your function suppopsed to do? Is your function supposed to print `test` or `test()`? Anyway, I think the strcat is the source of the strange behavior but its hard to give an answer without knowing exactly what you want. The best thing I can suggest is that you should fill your programs with printf statements showing the state of the functionName buffer throughout the execution of the algorithm. That should clear things up a lot.

Comment: It should be printing `test()` but yeah I'll definitely try the printf statments

Comment: I understood that its supposed to print `test()` but what is the `test()` supposed to mean? Why can't you just `printf("%s", args)` and be done with it?

Comment: Because the point of the function is to analyze the text passed in and perform some block of code depending on what it finds is in that text.

Comment: OK. Are you familiar with *lexing* and *parsing*, btw? Its a more robust way to build interpreters than just doing ad-hoc string munging.

Comment: Not really, do you have a good source I could check out or do you know any place I could read about it?

Comment: I don't know of any tutorials out of the top of my head but the traditional C tools for this are `flex` for writing lexers and `bison` for writing bottom-up parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `strcat` concatenates strings. At `strcat(functionName, fiterator);` you're concatenating the string `fiterator` to the string `functionName`, but what you want is to append the pointed `char` to `functionName`.

At the first iteration, `fiterator` is pointing to the first letter, so it is equal to the string `test()`, which you concatenate to the empty string. At the second iteration, `fiterator` is pointing to the second letter and it just really is the string `est()`. When both strings get joined, that is when you get `test()est()`.

Also, your iterator stops at `(` so you will never get `test()`, only `test`.

Try something like `functionName[i++] = *fiterator`, where `i` is an integer for the char position, starting in `0`.

```
  int i = 0;
  char functionName[25] = {};
  for (argsp = args; *argsp != '\0'; argsp++)
  {
    if (*argsp == '(')
    {
      char *fiterator;
      for (fiterator = args; *fiterator != '('; fiterator++)
      {
        functionName[i++] = *fiterator;
      }
    }
  }
```